# Extracting Post Data using the Express Router

Tags: javascript, post, request, router

My question is why request events fire when I DO NOT use the Express Router, but when I do use it, my request.on('data', ...) and request.on('end', ...) events don't fire.  I am guessing it has something to do with callbacks but it could also be me making a mistake.

I have a 'form' with the following:

```
<form method="post" action="/">
  <input type="text" name="user[name]">
  <input type="text" name="user[email]">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**IF** I put the following in my app.js file, everything works properly

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  var body = '';

  req.on('data', (data) => {
    body += data;
  });

  req.on('end', () => {
    var post = qs.parse(body);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(post)); 
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

**HOWEVER** if I use the Router so my app.js has

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes);
```

and my index.js has

```
  router.post('/', (request, response) => {
  var body = '';
  console.log('in here');

  request.on('data', (chunk) => {
    body += chunk;

    if(body.length > 10e6){
        request.connection.destroy();
    }
  });

  request.on("end", () => {
    var form = qs.parse(body);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(form));
    response.redirect('/');
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Then the 'data' and 'end' events are never called suggesting (to me at least) that router.post is a callback and the events have already been called.

Is my logic correct?  If so that is unfortunate as I can't use this method and must use body-parser.

Answer (score 0):

Are exporting router in `router/index.js`?

ie:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', (request, response) => {
  // some stuff
});

module.exports = router;
```

http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router

Comment: Good idea to check, but yes i am